# How to make an ice pack that doesn't leak

Tags: home, water, sports

Sometimes when I am playing sports or working out, I hurt something and I need an ice pack. Usually, I will use a bag ice of wrapped in a paper towel, but this always leaks after 15-25 minutes. **Is there any way to make an ice pack that won't leak?**

**Edit**: A bag of ice leaks through the corners of the bag

Comment: Are you asking about leaking *from inside the bag* or condensation from the outside? I've never had a problem with regular ziploc-type bags actually leaking, but the answers given seem to imply that's the issue (and don't really do anything for condensation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best option is to use a frozen sponge inside of a Ziploc bag. This works because when the sponge melts it will use it sponginess to soak up the water and make sure it doesn't leak.

<sup>From [thekitchn.com](http://www.thekitchn.com/make-diy-ice-packs-from-a-kitchen-sponge-my-kitchen-escapades-176888)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Cool! I like this one!

Answer (score 1):

Agree that investing in a pack is wise.

For future reference though: if you need an ice pack that can easily wrap around or drape over body parts---**frozen green peas** are the ticket. Leave them in the bag.

Men undergoing vasectomy are often advised to invest in some frozen green peas before the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you sport a lot you should invest in a gel-pack or two. They're not expensive. The benefit of gel-packs is that they don't freeze. A frozen block of ice only has a small contact area. The gel-pack has gel which isn't frozen so you can get a much larger contact area by wrapping it around.

If you want to go cheaper you could look at cooling elements you use for a coolbox. They're very cheap but blocks of ice.

And the very very cheap way is using icecube-bags you get in the supermarket.

Keep normal precautions though, never let it touch the skin directly, just like with ice.